# socket.io- how to pass socket id as query param?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm able to get socket id of a client when I `console.log()` it. Can anyone tell me how to pass it as a `query param` in the context mentioned below:

```
var params = {
    userId: 5,
    userType: 2
};

// create a new websocket
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000', { query: params });
socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('okay '+socket.id);
});
```

In this example, a user connects to the server and he passes a few values as the parameter upon establishing a socket connection.

But how can I pass socket id along with them?

**Socket IO version: 2.***

Comment: `io.on('connect', (socket) => {
   socket.id you will have the id on the server side
})`

Answer (score -1):

> This is a bit ambiguous, you can't send in query params the socket.id cause you receive the socket.id by connecting to socket.io server.

So if you really want to do that you connect second time. But in my opinion it is a very bad practice.